# Phaser 2: how to make masked area non clickable

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, game-engine, phaser-framework

I am new to Phaser (v 2.3.0). I have a sprite which is clickable and I have masked it with graphics (rectangle). The sprite is perfectly being masked but when I am clicking beyond mask area it is being clicked. I do not want my hidden area of sprite clickable. Hope I have explained it.
How can I achieve it. Help please! these tiles are scrollable.

**EDIT:-**    The hidden portion of tiles below the white line is also clickable which I don't want.
[image]

Comment: Can you maybe add a screenshot and draw a rectangles on it where you expect to be able to click?

Comment: I updated the problem.